# Wrap a synchronous function in Asynchronous call c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have a server, which must poll an equipment through the network, to obtain information, process it and then send it to the users.
The equipment survey becomes a synchronous blocking function.

My question is:

How to create an own asynchronous function version to perform this function using Task or another asynchronous pattern???

Consider the following code to get information from equipment:

```
IEnumerable<Logs> GetDataFromEquipment(string ipAddress)
        {
            Equipment equipment = new Equipment();
            //Open communication with equipment. Blocking code.
            int handler = equipment.OpenCommunication(ipAddress);
            //get data from equipment. Blocking code.
            IEnumerable<Logs> logs = equipment.GetLogs(handler);
            //close communication with equipment
            equipment.CloseCommunication(handler);

            return logs;
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: You make `GetLogs` asynchronous first.

Comment: how can I do it...

Comment: you have to make your IO methods async .

post OpenCommunication method for example.
and i'll first show you how to do that. 
what is your communication implemented with ? 
what .net facility/class ?

Comment: If you don't have access/possibility to change code of `Equipment` class, then you only approach is to run that method on another thread - `Task.Run` can be simple enough. In case you have access to `Equipment` class - add asynchronous methods for `Open..`, `GetLogs` and `Close..`. All IO operation can and should be done with `async-await` approach which will save you from wasting thread resource of your application for only waiting for response

Comment: The Equipment class is part of an external library of the equipment manufacturer. I use them to communicate with Equipment. How do I convert these synchronous calls into IO methods async?

Comment: I don't have access/possibility to change code of Equipment class.

Comment: Is a server because I have to poll multiple Equipment and send the information to several clients.

Comment: Is not a WCF server. The Logs data once read and processed are sent to the clients through an FTP server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use async/await

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Logs>> GetDataFromEquipment(string ipAddress)
    {

        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Equipment equipment = new Equipment();
            //Open communication with equipment. Blocking code.
            int handler = equipment.OpenCommunication(ipAddress);
            //get data from equipment. Blocking code.
            IEnumerable<Logs> logs = equipment.GetLogs(handler);
            //close communication with equipment
            equipment.CloseCommunication(handler);

            return logs;
        });

        return await task;
    }
```

Comment: Task.Run () create a thread in a ThreadPool, and code is blocking, is correct use the Task.Run in this case???

Comment: Call equipment.GetLogs(handler); delay a few seconds to respond. Blocking the Thread in the ThreadPool, I have read It's a bad practice...

Comment: Call `equipment.GetLogs(handler);` delay a few seconds to respond. Blocking the Thread in the ThreadPool, I have read It's a bad practice...

Comment: @J.Doe2017 - you're not so much 'blocking' the thread as simply using it, specifically *to avoid* blocking a thread you consider more important; e.g. perhaps the UI thread.  If you have no access to change `Equipment` to be async, this is the only way.  Well... there are of course many other ways, but you're not going to achieve a proper thread-sparing, async-await situation without `Equipment` being rewritten to properly support `async-await`-style asynchrony.

Comment: There are hundreds of Equipment that I have to survey from time to time. Assuming that in the middle of the process of `GetLogs`, you lose the communication with the Equipment, delay in giving the answer several minutes, now, hundreds of Thread in ThreadPool will remain in blocking state, would this be dangerous? It's my doubt.

Comment: .NET won't give you hundreds of threads to use, certainly not in its default configuration anyway.  What you would end up with is a lot of tasks *queued* for the thread pool, but just a few threads working on it at any one time.  Even so, better the thread pool is busy processing this than your UI thread (or other threads you need more responsive).

Comment: Thanks very much, sellotape