# Call a sync function asynchronously for UI responsiveness

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have a sync method `GetReports()` which return value will be used to set the data source of a UI control. It may take a while to run. Is it idiomatic way to call it asynchronously as the following?

```
var l = new List<...>();
await Task.Run(() => l = GetReports().ToList());
UIControl.DataSource = l;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283026/wrap-a-synchronous-function-in-asynchronous-call-c-sharp.

Comment: @ne1410s: "Await is for responding synchronously to async methods" -- no. `await` is for asynchronously waiting for "awaitables", including tasks, such that the executing method yields control back to the caller until the awaitable has completed. In a UI context such as [tag:winforms], `await Task.Run(…)` is fine and common. Whether it is "idiomatic" is a matter of opinion, so as long as the code above does what the OP wants it to (i.e. there's no actual _problem_ to solve), the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You're question makes no sense.  An async method can just call a sync method.  Calling an sync method asynchronously is actually worse in performance and memory usage.

Comment: It's important for UI responsibility.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - Do you mean "UI Responsiveness" rather than "UI Resposibility"?

Comment: @Enigmativity, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    Observable
        .Start(() => GetReports().ToList())
        .ObserveOn(UIControl)
        .Subscribe(list => UIControl.DataSource = list);
```

This nicely pushes to a new thread and then pulls it back before updating the `DataSource`.

If you need to cancel before it has finished just call `subscription.Dispose();`.

If your call to `GetReports` is cancellable then you can do this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    Observable
        .FromAsync(ct => GetReports(ct))
        .Select(x => x.ToList())
        .ObserveOn(UIControl)
        .Subscribe(list => UIControl.DataSource = list);
```

Calling `subscription.Dispose()` will now also cancel the task.

Comment: I wanted to learn and use Rx for a long time ago. But it seems it's heavy/over-skilled for a lot of tasks. This one sounds a good fit considering it can handle canceling gracefully.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - I use Rx for all of my event, task, or async calls. It's an extremely powerful library. It's cognitively heavy if you wanted to learn the whole thing but generally very graceful and a handful of techniques gets you a long way.

Comment: If the function `GetReports` accepts a canceling token (`GetReports(cancelingToken)`), is it possible to let `subscription.Dispose();` set the canceling token?

Comment: @ca9163d9 - Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are after responsive *UI* and to run a long running CPU workload (and not Scalability as such) then this is fine and will achieve what you want. Essentially it will

1. Start a new thread (term used loosely)
2. Create a continuation
3. Give back the thread that calls it (in your case the UI thread)
4. Execute the workload
5. Run the continuation

   - 5a Execute everything after the `await` on the thread you called it on

Although *Tasks* aren't threads, you will find this will steal a thread from the *Thread Pool* to do your workload, and it will free up the *UI Thread* until its finished

You could also do the same thing with the older style `Task.Run` and `ContinueWith`.

There is another school of thought as well, that if you use the [`TaskFactory.StartNew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=netframework-4.7.2) with the `TaskCreationOptions` as `LongRunning` it will hint to the Default `TaskScheduler` that you want to create a thread external to the *Thread Pool*. This gives the advantage of leaving the *Thread Pool* with more resources.

On saying that, `TaskFactory.StartNew` is the grand daddy of the *Task* creation methods, it has its own quirks, and you probably should only use it when you specifically feel the need to do so. I would just stick with what you have.

The last note, although it seems like a good idea to wrap this workload in a method and call it `async`, its generally not a good idea; and if you must wrap, its best left to caller to decide these things. So once again you are doing the right thing. *Stephen Cleary* talks about `Fake Async` and `Async Wrappers` and the reasons why you shouldn't have a need to do it in

[Task.Run Etiquette and Proper Usage](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html)

Comment: do you think there's a need to explicitly specify the background thread for the scheduler, or does the `LongRunning` flag also take care of that hint?

Comment: @JoshE  when you use `Task.Run` the potential resulting thread already runs as a background thread (you can test it out for your self), however they come from the thread pool(either standard or IO type). In theory `LongRunning`  is only a hint, but in practice (and implementation details aside) i have never seen a situation where it doesn't do this. However this may change in future version, i seriously doubt it though